# Why is the forEach() method not displaying setting background images

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

So, I am currently trying my hands at js as I have just finished the basics.
Currently, I am stuck at a simple slideshow, that I am trying to create with only forEach() method as I am using an array to store images. The problem is that the code doesn't set the background image at all. Although, when logged on console, it is showing the url's of the images as expected. Here's the code,

```
    let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    const imagesArray = [
   'https://images.pexels.com/photos/572897/pexels-photo-572897.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
   'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2832039/pexels-photo-2832039.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
   'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2574643/pexels-photo-2574643.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940']
    setTimeout(imagesArray.forEach(function(path) {
    slider.style.backgroundImage = "url "+(path);  }),400)
```

Comment: One more thing, I think the part where I have set the image as background is wrong as it works fine with a single image.

Comment: _"The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method of the `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` mixin (and successor to `Window.setTimeout()`) sets a timer which executes **a function or specified piece of code** once the timer expires."_ (you should not use the _"piece of code"_ part unless you know what you're doing, because it is essentially an `eval()` call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You are not providing a callback in your `setTimeout()` method
2. The logic of swapping out and image every 400ms is incorrect. You should be calling `window.setTimeout()` for every image you come across, but increment the duration based on the index that you are currently at:

   - 1st image: wait 400ms
   - 2nd image: wait another 400ms after the first (so total wait: 800ms)
   - 3rd image: wait another 400ms after the second (so total wait: 1200ms)

See proof-of-concept example below. I have increased the waiting duration to 1000ms per image for convenience:

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const imagesArray = [
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=3'
]
imagesArray.forEach((image, i) => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    slider.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
  }, 1000 * i);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

---

### Advanced solution with async/await

If you really want to challenge yourself, you can do it with an async/await + for loop combination. The advantage of this is that you don't need to set an arbitrary large timeout for a very large image array, since the for loop will wait for fixed amount of seconds before moving on to the next iteration.

You can use the [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) here, since we no longer need access to the index to set a custom duration for each iteration.

```js
async function wait(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const imagesArray = [
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/940x650?text=3'
];

async function runSlideShow() {
  for (let image of imagesArray) {
    await wait(1000);
    slider.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
  }

}

// Since we cannot have top-level async/await,
// we need to do the for loop in an async function
// and then invoke it at runtime
runSlideShow();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you implement this using forEach().

Comment: @bruTeFoRcE `imagesArray.forEach((currentImage, index) => { setTimeout(() => { slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + ${currentImage} + ")" }, (1000 * index)); })`

Comment: @bruTeFoRcE Yes, see updated answer. For the async/await solution, you cannot use `Array.prototype.forEach` because it does not support async operations and generators.

Comment: @Andreas Your code works when you replace template literals inside of inverted commas with the right syntax.
        "url(" + currentImage + ")"

Comment: @bruTeFoRcE Ups... I first used a template literal but as I couldn't get the backticks to work in the comment I switch back to string concatenation - missing to fix the `${currentImage}` part... -> @bruTeFoRcE `imagesArray.forEach((currentImage, index) => { setTimeout(() => { slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + currentImage + ")" }, (1000 * index)); })`

Comment: Why? Just accept Terrys answer as it is already a part of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` needs a callback function. You need to write it as:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   imagesArray.forEach(function(path) {
    slider.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + path + ")";  
  }
}),400);
```